# (GDB) Breakpoints and Disassemble

Tags: c, linux, gdb, breakpoints, disassembly

I've been recently interested in reading books and articles about hacking and I found out that *Hacking:The art of exploitation* is just a must read title. I am following the basic tutorials on how to work with standard Linux tools and analyze your code (Programming chapter). I am not a beginner in programming but working with Linux terminal is quite new for me. I am using the latest release of Kali Linux.

Right now my simple program below should be used to analyze how stack segment works.

```
int main(){
  void stack_func(int a,int b, int c, int d){
    char first;
    int second;

    first = 'c';
    second = 220;
  }

  stack_func(1,2,3,4);
  return 0;
}
```

The first problem is I cannot add any **breakpoints** for internal  functions. Neither mine functions like *stack_func()* nor functions from libraries like *strcpy* etc. According to the book the pending breakpoint should resolve. Mine is just ignored and program finishes.

```
root@root:~/Folder# gdb -q ./stack
Reading symbols from ./stack...done.
(gdb) b stack_func
Function "stack_func" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (stack_func) pending.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /root/Folder/stack 
[Inferior 1 (process 20421) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

The second problem is that **disassemble** also doesn't work for my function. Again according to the book I should be able to see assembler code for my function *stack_func()* but the result is below.

```
(gdb) disass stack_func()
No symbol "stack_func" in current context.
(gdb)
```

I appologize for any grammatical errors in text. :)

Comment: Your no-side-effect function is probably just removed by the compiler, or at least inlined.

Comment: Have you tried moving the `stack_func` outside of `main`?

Comment: Yeah I tried the error message looks like this now. `You can't do that without a process to debug.`

Comment: Message from what? Which step? Please be precise when you are providing info.

Comment: And it's `disass stack_func`. That is, without the parentheses.

Comment: Yeah I am sry. Right now I am confused I was googling literally whole day a tried it without parentheses and suddenly everything is working even breakpoints. I am sorry for wasting your time then and ty for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you defined `stack_func` inside another function. This is called [nested function](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) and it is gcc extension in GNU C. This function has a bit other symbol name than you expect. To find out it's exact symbol name you can use `nm` tool:

```
[ tmp]$ nm a.out |grep stack_func
00000000004004a6 t stack_func.1761
```

And set breakpoint and disassemble in gdb:

```
[ tmp]$ gdb -q ./a.out 
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
(gdb) b 'stack_func.1761'
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004ba: file 111.c, line 6.
(gdb) disassemble 'stack_func.1761'
Dump of assembler code for function stack_func:
   0x00000000004004a6 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x00000000004004a7 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000004004aa <+4>: mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
   0x00000000004004ad <+7>: mov    %esi,-0x18(%rbp)
   0x00000000004004b0 <+10>:    mov    %edx,-0x1c(%rbp)
   0x00000000004004b3 <+13>:    mov    %ecx,-0x20(%rbp)
   0x00000000004004b6 <+16>:    mov    %r10,-0x28(%rbp)
   0x00000000004004ba <+20>:    movb   $0x63,-0x1(%rbp)
   0x00000000004004be <+24>:    movl   $0xdc,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x00000000004004c5 <+31>:    nop
   0x00000000004004c6 <+32>:    pop    %rbp
   0x00000000004004c7 <+33>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```